# Removing all of a subclassed UIView from self.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a bunch of UIViews that I subclassed that I have been adding to `self.view` e.g.:

```
MySpecialView *myView = [[MySpecialView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Now I want to remove them all from `self.view` but only those custom ones. I don't want to remove any of the others (I have some other views with options in them etc). Is there anyway of doing this at all? Can I loop through all the subviews and check their type? Any pointers on this would be great! Thanks!

Comment: you can give the custom views tag and remove them by calling [myCustomview removeFromSuperView]

Comment: can't understand your question. what is the meaning of  (I have some other views with options in them etc)?

Comment: or you can check if view belongs tomyspecialview class or not, and then remove it

Answer (score 4):

Try a loop like this

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MySpecialView class]])
        [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This simply iterates through all of the subviews and removes any that are of class `MySpecialView`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** way

```
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if subview.isKindOfClass(MyClass) {
            // Is that class!
        } else if subview.isMemberOfClass(MyClass) {
            // Is that class or a subclass of that class!
        }
    }
```